# Max value in a vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to compute the maximum value in an int[]. The program below crashes but I can't understand why. Is there a problem with the `Test` class? Thank you.

```
class Max {
    int *max;
public:
    Max() {
        max = NULL;
    }
    ~Max() {
        if (max)
            delete max;
    }
    void compute(int N[], int n) {
        this->~Max();
        max = new int(N[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (*max < N[i])
                *max = N[i];
    }
    void print() {
        cout << "Max= " << *max << endl;
    }
};

class Test {
public:
    static Max& getMax(int N[], int n) {
        Max m;
        m.compute(N, n);
        return m;
    }
};


void main() {
    int N[] = { 8,9,7,8,10,6 };
    Test::getMax(N, sizeof(N) / sizeof(int)).print();
}
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't just using [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)?

Comment: `this->~Max();`??? Why would you do this?

Comment: Same as NathanOliver, and `std::vector` as well...

Comment: And dynamically allocating an `int` wrapped in a class, and returning a ref to a local variable..  do you not have compiler warnings switched on?

Comment: yes, I get that there can be other easier ways of dealing with this problem, but still, I'd like to know where's the fault in this code. How can I deal with that out of scope issue in getMax()? Is there a particular problem with that destructor call?

Comment: Doing it at all is the problem! Can you explain why you do it?

Comment: You could use vector, unique_ptr (even you don't need). And don't call a destructor like that, you probably will never need that

Comment: Why all the classes? C++ isn't java, you don't have to put everything into a class. And there's no reason for any classes at all to do this task.

Comment: Why are you using an `int*` to a dynamically allocated `int` to hold a value that is clearly better handled with a simple non-dynamic `int` instead? You don't need a pointer in this scenario at all, especially since your `Max` class is not following the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) correctly. Also, `Test::getMax()` returns a `Max&` reference to a local `Max` object that is destroyed when `getMax()` returns, leaving the caller with a dangling reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Max value in a vector

That isn't a vector. It's an array. Vectors of integers are called `std::vector<int>`. You should probably use one.

```
void compute(int N[], int n) {
    this->~Max();
```

The object referred to as `*this` is officially *dead* after this line. You can't legally do anything with it except de-allocate the memory, or use placement new to construct another instance over its corpse.

What you *actually* do - being neither of those things - is illegal and immoral.

Having a pointer here (and re/de/allocating it) doesn't even achieve anything, as far as I can tell. If you can just write `int max;` and avoid dynamic allocation, do that.

```
static Max& getMax(int N[], int n) {
    Max m;
    m.compute(N, n);
    return m;
}
```

Returning a reference to a temporary is also illegal. Either

- return `m` by value (you'll need to write proper copy and move constructors and assignment operators if you want the dynamic allocation to work correctly, although just removing it would save a lot of work and bugs)
- or just return the calculated max value and print it outside (there's no obvious reason the `Max` class should be coupled to `std::cout`).

---

To sum up, my recommendations in preference order are:

1. use [`std::vector<int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)
2. if you *must* write your own versions, `max` should still be a function returning the result, rather than a method which mutates an object to ... store the result for later? So:

   ```
   int compute_max(int const *n, int nlen) {
       // handle corner cases
       if (nlen < 1) return std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

       int result = n[0];
       for (int i = 1; i < nlen; i++)
           if (result < n[i])
               result = n[i];
       return result;
   }
   ```
3. if you *must* have a stateful `Max` class (which still seems like a very odd design to me), just remove the dynamic allocation
4. if you *must* have the dynamic allocation, you still need to stop explicitly calling the destructor, will need to implement copy and move constructors/assignment operators, and should ideally use `std::unique_ptr<int>` instead of a raw pointer

Whichever implementation of `Max` you prefer (and I want to stress  that options 3&4 are very distant third and fourth best options, for use only under very unsual or artificial conditions), you *must* not return a reference to a local variable in `getMax()`. Or anywhere else, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to use `std::vector`/`std::array` with `std::max_element`. I recommend to first learn modern c++ with stl containers and algorithms and later you can learn about low level features.

But for you to learn here are the errors in your code:

1. Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`

   ```
   Max() {
       max = nullptr;
   }
   ```
2. Don't call a destructor

   ```
   this->~Max();
   ```
3. Don't return a reference to a local variable

   ```
   static Max& getMax(int N[], int n) { // 
       Max m;
       m.compute(N, n);
       return m;
   }
   ```
4. Don't use `using namespace std;`
5. Remember to call a `delete` for each `new` and a `delete[]` for each `new []`. (Avoid `new`, `new []`, `delete` and `delete[]` if possible)
6. You don't need a pointer for `max`. `int max;` would also work after you adept your code a little bit.

Comment: (3) returns a copy not a reference. However the code violates the rule of three and will encounter memory corruption.

Comment: 5. a) Remember not to call `delete` each time you do not use `new`, because a `std::vector` already does manage the memory for you. ;)

Comment: @RaymondChen (3) In the original code returns a reference. I already fixed it. Now I changed it back to show the problem.

Comment: "Don't call a destructor" - it's not that calling a destructor is bad - it certainly has its place (which isn't here).  It's that calling once more than once is UB; and it gets called once by default.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use `std::vector` and `std::max_element` but the real issue with your code (apart from the many bugs) is how convoluted it is. Programming in C++ is easier than you are making out.

Here's how to write the same code in a straightforward manner, no classes are needed for this simple task.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int compute(int N[], int n) {
    int max = N[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (max < N[i])
            max = N[i];
    return max;
}

void print(int max) {
    cout << "Max= " << max << endl;
}

int main() {
    int N[] = { 8,9,7,8,10,6 };
    print(compute(N, sizeof(N) / sizeof(int)));
}
```

Untested code.